# Custom field to display custom image instead of featured image

Tags: wordpress

What custom field should I use in Wordpress in order to use my a custom image rather than the 'featured image' chosen for the post?

This code is from the custom page template that functions as the front blog page and shows all posts:

```
<?php $thumb = '';
    $width = 184;
    $height = 184;
    $classtext = '';
        $titletext = get_the_title();

    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext);
    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"]; ?>

    <?php if ( $thumb <> '' && !$et_ptemplate_showthumb ) { ?>
    <div class="et_pt_thumb alignleft">
    <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail[""], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
    </div> <!-- end .thumb -->
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: I am sorry for being so strict for your other question. I should've shown more compassion definitely. Please don't take it too personal. Yet it would be a good idea to take some advises into account. Anyway, I just felt to say sorry. Hope you sorted your issue out.

Answer (score 0):

You would add an image URL or attachment ID in a [Custom Field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and use the function [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to get the value and print the image in the theme.

But, it's easier to use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) and its [Image Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/).